# NRF52840 interrupt forwarding

Tags: cortex-m4, nordic

I've build a bootloader for the NRF52840, and inserted my own MBR.  I've incorporated the s140 binary into code, so I'm trying to get this fly after programming.

It takes off, but dies, coming back into the bootloader hardfault.  I think this is somewhat wrong, because I'm pretty sure the vectors should be "forwarded?" to the softdevice binary at the softdevice vector table at 0x1000.  This mechanism isn't very well documented in NRF docs.  Is this forwarding some manual NRF handling done in their MBR?  Any other ideas appreciated.

```
#define MBR_VECTOR_TABLE       (0x20000000)
#define MBR_START_POS          (0x20000004)
#define SOFTDEVICE_END          0x00026000
#define FLASH_APPLICATION_START   0x00001000

typedef void (*p_function)(void);
p_function p_jump_function;

static void minimalJumpToApp(void) {

  *(uint32_t *)MBR_VECTOR_TABLE = FLASH_APPLICATION_START;
  *(uint32_t *)MBR_START_POS = SOFTDEVICE_END;

  uint32_t jump_address = *(__IO uint32_t *)(FLASH_APPLICATION_START + 4);
  p_jump_function = (p_function)jump_address;
  __set_CONTROL(0);
  __set_MSP(*(__IO uint32_t *)FLASH_APPLICATION_START);
  // jump!
  p_jump_function();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vector table relocation is not a nRF52840 feature per-se. It is an ARM-v7m feature implemented in Cortex-M4F of the chip.

You should have a look at [ARM-v7m Architecture Reference Manual (DDI0403E.b)](https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/5f8fef3af86e16515cdbf816), Chapter B3.2.5, page B3-657. It describes the VTOR register that holds the base address for the interrupt vector table, which happens to sit at address 0 at reset.

You may modify value of this register just before jumping to the entry point of the application image, or let this be overridden by the application itself, depending on the convention you set between the two.

Comment: There's a handy guide [here](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ka001423/latest) giving example code for setting VTOR before the jump.

Answer (score 1):

For ARM Cortex-M devices which only support THUMB mode the least significant bit of a branch address needs to be set to indicate THUMB mode, otherwise a hard fault occurs. See [Pointers to functions in Thumb state](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0471/m/interworking-arm-and-thumb/pointers-to-functions-in-thumb-state) in the ARM documentation.

Try changing the code to set the least significant bit in the following statement which sets up the function pointer for the application:

```
p_jump_function = (p_function)jump_address | 1;
```

See [TMS320F28384S: Code branch in CM4](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/c2000-microcontrollers-group/c2000/f/c2000-microcontrollers-forum/1064129/tms320f28384s-code-branch-in-cm4/3941401#3941401) for a similar issue on a different Cortex-M4 MCU.

**Update**: On re-reading the code in the question this might not be the issue, as the value of `jump_address` is read from contents of address `FLASH_APPLICATION_START + 4` in the flash. This answer may be incorrect.

Comment: Well, this code does work on STM32L4 series.  I'm seeing some activity, but I'm pretty sure its dying due to the softdevice.  Its a frustrating black box.

Comment: @ErikFriesen The fact that the code does work on the STM32L4 series would be useful to edit into the question. I don't have experience of a NRF52840, but on other Cortex-M devices have been able to use a JTAG debugger to single step instructions to locate when a hard fault occurs. Do you have the option of single stepping instructions?

Comment: It’s really difficult with crossworks to single step code without source.  I did solve this now, it’s a strange combination of issues. TLDR don’t use closed sourced binaries if you can help it.